# How to toggle text with a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the text **not rated** with **100%** if you press the up arrow button or **0%** if you press the down arrow button. I would like to accomplish this with either js or jQuery I just don't know how to go about it.

```
<div class="votesystem">

  <input type="checkbox" class="votes" role="button">

    <label for="voteup" onclick=""><span class="voteswitch"> <img src="images/voteup.png" data-value="up"/><br /><br /></span>

<p>Not rated</p>

     <span class="voteswitch"><img src="images/votedown.png" data-value="down" /></span> </label>     

 </div>
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, I'm going to elaborate on the question to clear up confusion. I found some code that contains a similar effect of what I want, except it hides the text: **Testing** when I would like to replace the text testing with another word when clicking the checkbox.

Also I would like to make it a radio button instead of checklist so the text changes depending on the button selected. Thanks for your help so far.

```
<label>Chanage text</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="test">

<div id="content" class="hide">
  <p>testing</p>
</div>
```

And the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hide').hide();
    $('#test').click(function(){
        $('#content').toggle();
    });        
});
```

Comment: The reason you're getting downvotes is because this is a rather easy "how-to" that can be googled. Give the P element an ID then target it with JS and replace InnerHTML.

Comment: First: Button's are not new `HTML5` elements... Second: Your code is malformed, you have two action elements inside one `label`, not good. and Third and more important: What have you tried so far? let us see your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Give your HTML an id or class (some kind of selector) then use jQuery/JavaScript to change your elements HTML based on your keyboard press.

**You could also get it by it's `<p>` tag as Bardyl mentioned but that is a bad idea if you may have multiple `<p>` tags at some point.**

```
<p id="foo">Not rated</p>

<script>
$("#foo").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 38) {
     $("#foo").html("100%");
  } else if (event.which == 40) {
     $("#foo").html("0%");
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show me an excample on jsfiddle is not working for me, and can you add 2 buttons that will control the text changes. The top button should toggle from Not Rated to 0 percent, and the bottom button should toggle between Not Rated and 100%